# Setting Value of Output Element via JavaScript in Edge and IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

I have an `output` tag whose value is set dynamically via JavaScript. This works just fine in Chrome and Firefox, but Microsoft browsers (IE and Edge) don't seem to recognize it, and the `value` is always empty for these tags.

HTML:

```js
    document.getElementById("owned").value = "Test 1";    
    document.getElementById("used").value = "Test 2";
```

```html
    <output class="output" id="owned"></output>
    <output class="output" id="used"></output>
```

It even works when I run the code snippet on Stack Overflow.

Question: Is there any reason why the values aren't being set on these browsers? Is there a file that I must import into my HTML for it to work on IE/Edge?

Comment: Opened this question link on IE 11 and the snippet does not work on it either

Comment: Output tag is not compatible with IE11 or Edge

Comment: MDN claims that IE doesn't support the `<output>` element.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/output#AutoCompatibilityTable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `span` and `.innerHTML`. `<output>` HTML tag seems to not work on Edge.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Edge added support for `<output>` [in version 14](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/outputelement?filter=f3f0000bf&search=output)*.

For now, you could test for support, optionally writing to the `textContent` property instead:

```js
var used = document.querySelector("#used");
var owned = document.querySelector("#owned");

// Temporarily fall back to textContent
var property = "value" in used ? "value" : "textContent";
used[ property ] = "Test 1";
owned[ property ] = "Test 2";
```

```html
<output class="output" id="owned"></output>  
<output class="output" id="used"></output>
```

<sup>*At the time of this writing, MS Edge 14 is only available to [*Insiders*](http://insider.windows.com/). It is scheduled for release on August 2, 2016 ([Windows 10 Anniversary Update](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2016/06/29/windows-10-anniversary-update-available-august-2/))</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This is a polyfill for the `<output>` element in IE11:

```
if (window.HTMLOutputElement === undefined) {
  Object.defineProperty(HTMLUnknownElement.prototype, 'value', {
    get: function () {
      if (this.tagName === 'OUTPUT') {
        return this.textContent;
      }
    },
    set: function (newValue) {
      if (this.tagName === 'OUTPUT') {
        this.textContent = newValue;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Only been tested for getting/setting the `value` property.